# Theano takes a few minutes to start a script running on GPU

Tags: python, gpgpu, theano

I start a script running on GPU as follows:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32,base_compiledir=../../temp python t.py
```

It sometimes takes a few minutes before it even starts: the first line of the script `t.py` is a print statement (viz. `print('start')`), and it will not get displayed before a few minutes.

If using the CPU, the print statement immediately appears:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu,floatX=float32,base_compiledir=../../temp python t.py
```

I killed all Python processes beforehand using `sudo pkill -9 python`. Running `nvidia-smi` shows that before running my script, no process uses any of the GPUs. (I use nVidia GPUs, specifically nVidia GeForce GTX Titan X)

I have noticed the issue arises in a screen session (using [GNU Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)), when it has been created a while ago (> half a day it seems). Killing the screen session and creating a new one solves the issue. However, I don't understand why it fixes the issue.

What could explain the issue?

---

Some timing:

Using the Python script:

```
import time
print('start import theano')
theano_import_start_time = time.time()
import theano
theano_import_duration = time.time() - theano_import_start_time
print('done import theano')
print('theano_import_duration: {0} seconds'.format(theano_import_duration))
```

run with the command:

```
francky@server:/scratch1/a/b$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32,base_compiledir=../../temp_compilation python -u test_import_theano.py
```

I get:

```
start import theano
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN X (CNMeM is disabled)
done import theano
theano_import_duration: 221.107403994 seconds
```

221 seconds is quite a long time to import a library. If I kill the screen and create a new one, the import time is around 1.1 seconds.

The slowness does seem reproducible: even if I run the import theano more than once, it still takes ~220 seconds (unless I kill and create a new screen). Also, I don't empty `base_compiledir`.

Comment: Is there an `import theano` statement before the `print` line? If yes, does the pause happen before or after the `Using gpu device 0: <GPU details>` statement that is printed by Theano automatically?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Good catch, there is a `import theano` before the print statement. I'll move the print statement before all imports next time I have this issue. It pauses before the `Using gpu device 0: <GPU details>` statement.

Comment: That usually means it's doing preliminary compilation. Is `../../temp` on a networked filesystem or somehow repeatedly deleted?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw (sorry for the delay, the problem hasn't reoccurred till now) You are right, that's the `import theano` that is taking a long time to complete: I tried with `print('start import theano'); import theano; print('done import theano')`. No compilation involved. I don't think it touches files from networked filesystems, but even if it did everything is 1 Gbps and local: it's typically not a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

If you empty the directory pointed to by the `base_compiledir` Theano flag and start your script you should expect `import theano` to take an unusually long time because the first import of theano will cause a bunch of compilation to occur behind the scenes. Subsequent runs should `import theano` much quicker because the setup compilation has already happened, as long as the `base_compiledir` has not been cleared in the interim.

Since Theano has to check that all the setup compilation is present in the cache, `import theano` can take a while to run even after the first time. This is especially true if the `base_compiledir` is on a networked, or otherwise slow, filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. The slowness does seem reproducible though: even if I run the `import theano` more than once, it still takes ~220 seconds. Also, I don't empty `base_compiledir`. After killing the screen and creating a new one, without changing anything else, the `import theano` then takes ~1 second.

Comment: If the compile directory is on a network filesystem, could your credentials have expired?